# Is oracle dropping database oracle XE?

Tags: oracle, download, oracle-xe

I'm trying to access the download for oracle XE on windows but it fails with 404 error.
Is Oracle leveraging its possession of mysql or is it a temporarily error?

Comment: I have answered this question to be helpful but I am also voting to close as Too Localized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not specific to Express Edition.  Pretty much *all* of the download links are broken - I also tried 11g Server and ApEx.  Ironically the MySQL links still seem to be working.

According to [this thread in the OTN Forums](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1082972&tstart=0) it is a problem with OTN site.  Basically nobody outside of the USA can download anything.   internal (bug) reference  : *iSupport 17538053 - Downloading from OTN is no more possible*

There is a post towards the end of that thread which has a potential workaround: use Firefox 3.5.9 with a manual proxy.  [Find it here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4355644#4355644).

Comment: As of now it's up and running again.